# Fan running at max speed after switching to ubuntu

Tags: overheating, fan

After switching to Ubuntu my laptop is heating. I didn't have this problem when I had windows 7.I changed my CPU to "Powersave" mode but it is still heating and the fan is running at maximum speed.How can i make it to not be at max speed all the time?

My processor is Intel Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz × 2 If this helps.

Comment: What brand and model number is your laptop?

Comment: Dell Inspiron N5110. The problem is that before i switched to ubuntu there was no heating. Now i have set the governor to powersave. I watch the CPU is showing no activity but the fan is running and the laptop keeps heating. Didn't have this problem with windows 7

Comment: Your CPU is a bit older, so its power saving features should be incorporated into the Linux kernel. It could be the GPU producing all the heat, though. What's the laptop's display adapter and which driver is it using? Please post the output of `sudo lshw -class display`.

Comment: *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:55 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller

Comment: `
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)`